# Invalid SOAP Fault Start element faultcode from namespace expected

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I am accessing a third party Web based API Travelport. It was working fine on pre-production credentials and URL until we decided to go to production. First i had this `charset=ISO-8859-1` issue which is solved by the help of [Connecting to a PHP Web service with WCF in C#](http://www.pathfindertech.net/connecting-to-a-php-web-service-with-wcf-in-c/) But now i am getting this exception
 `Server returned an invalid SOAP Fault. Please see InnerException for more details.
     - Start element 'faultcode' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'SOAP-ENV:faultcode' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'. Line 1, position 135.`

This is the `XML` in my `web_messages.svclog`

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>0</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
    <Level>8</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-07-06T07:43:46.8130015Z" />
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{992e2e7a-6cd7-475c-8b1f-684b90329a80}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="iisexpress" ProcessID="5368" ThreadID="24" />
    <Channel />
    <Computer>PRODUCTION-2</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
        <DataItem>
            <MessageLogTraceRecord Time="2015-07-06T11:43:46.7920015+04:00" Source="TransportReceive" Type="System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamedMessage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
                <HttpResponse>
                    <StatusCode>InternalServerError</StatusCode>
                    <StatusDescription>Internal Server Error</StatusDescription>
                    <WebHeaders>
                        <Connection>close</Connection>
                        <Content-Length>554</Content-Length>
                        <Content-Type>text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1</Content-Type>
                        <Date>Mon, 06 Jul 2015 07:46:08 GMT</Date>
                        <Server>Apache-Coyote/1.1</Server>
                    </WebHeaders>
                </HttpResponse>
                <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                    <SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header>
                    <SOAP-ENV:Body>... stream ...</SOAP-ENV:Body>
                </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
            </MessageLogTraceRecord>
        </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
```

I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287635/how-to-handle-incorrect-soap-fault-in-wcf) guy having the same problem but i am unable to apply this solution, I am new to WCF Please help me solve this issue

---

**Update**

After utilizing `IClientMessageInspector` and implementing it in custom class i am able to get this `SOAP` details

```
<SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
    <SOAP-ENV:faultcode>500</SOAP-ENV:faultcode>
    <SOAP-ENV:faultstring>EntGWConnectServlet:29d64cb14e628c682c7b50 - Internal Error: nullnull</SOAP-ENV:faultstring>
    <SOAP-ENV:faultactor></SOAP-ENV:faultactor>
    <SOAP-ENV:detail>EntGWConnectServlet:29d64cb14e628c682c7b50 - Internal Error: nullnull</SOAP-ENV:detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

**Still not able to get the exact error**

As i mentioned above, after applying the solution i am still not getting the proper error so that i can rectify it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle incorrect SOAP fault in WCF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287635/how-to-handle-incorrect-soap-fault-in-wcf)

Comment: I applied the solution but still can't get more then the xml in update section of question.

Comment: The error is that the 3rd party is sending an incorrect SOAP fault. The <faultcode>, <faultstring>, <faultactor>, <detail> elements must NOT be namespace-qualified. For you that means: 1) Contact the 3rd party and tell them to send correct SOAP faults. 2) Until they do, use the IClientMessageInspector to not only inspect, but **change** the received fault. [The MSDN forum link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/435850aa-bf74-4158-a29a-256135207948) in [the accepted answer to the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2291737/626761) contains some code to start from.

Comment: @nodots I notice that the incorrect fault in the linked question has the *exact same* namespace prefix. This suggests to me that the API referenced in this question, as well as that one, use the same framework that itself has a bug. I mention this purely out of interest as it might be conscientious to contact that framework's maintainers and get them to fix it...

Comment: I've put a support ticket but they are saying that it's working at their end, i provided them with the XML request and this response.

Comment: I've applied the solution in the links and now i am catching the exception. but the message is like this `500EntGWConnectServlet:79220f9614e63b4ee8b74bf - Internal Error`